# Update new table using other table data with few modification in new table

Tags: sql, oracle

I have one table named "Input_Data" like below, from this table i am going to take input values for other table.

```
**TN         start_date   operator**
12345       12-May-2015       123
67890       14-May-2015       456
```

And another table "Output_data" as below, this table will get updated as per values coming from "Input_Data"

```
**SOURCE_ID EFFECTIVE_DATE  EXPIRATION_DATE PROVIDER_ID**
  12345     01-Jan-2014                       555
```

As 12345 source_id already present in Output_Data table, in this case i want to update entry for source_id 12345 coming from "Input_Data" table such that earlier entry in "Output_Data" table will expire with new entry’s start_date. And another row will be inserted for new entry. Hence "Output_Data" should look like below:

```
**DEST_ID      EFFECTIVE_DATE   EXPIRATION_DATE PROVIDER_ID**
  12345          01-Jan-2014    12-May-2015       555
  12345          12-May-2015                      123
  67890          14-May-2015                      456
```

I am new to SQL, and trying with some query like below for above task:

```
select A.TN, A.START_DATE, A.OPERATOR, NVL(A.expiration_date,  
       to_date('31-12-  9999 00:00:00','DD-MM-YYYY hh24:mi:ss')) 
from
    (select tn,start_date,destination,
    Lead(effective_date) over (partition by tn order by effective_date ) as  expiration_date
    from
        (select op.DEST_ID tn, op.EFFECTIVE_DATE start_date, 
                op.PROVIDER_ID destination
         from Output_Data op, Input_Data ip where op.DEST_ID=ip.TN 
         union
         select ip.TN tn, ip.start_date effective_date, ip.operator destination 
         from Input_Data ip) T) A 
         where effective_date != NVL(expiration_date,to_date('31-12-9999','DD-MM-YYYY hh24:mi:ss'))
```

But above query is not even getting executed so I am not able to check the output.

Comment: you tagged mysql, sql-server and oracle!? Should the query work for every of these DBMS?

Comment: You missed `PostgreSQL` and `DB2`.

Comment: I have tagged all of them just to get answers. I am expecting the query which will work on Oracle.

Comment: Don't tag products not used!!! See now you've got people wasting time writing answers that don't work with Oracle!

Comment: @RamMore - Accurate tagging is crucial to the proper functioning of SatckOverflow.  Please don't waste people's time by asking them to work on solutions you won't use.  That's a very poor show.

Comment: this is way too complicated for what I'm trying to do in oracle :D

Comment: Sorry @RamMore but this is way too complicated for me, can't get it to work in Oracle :( if anyone else wants to give it a try: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!4/d2304

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Before downvoting read this: Question was posted with tags for sqlserver, mysql and oracle, oracle answer is not ready yet, working on it

This is for sql-server:

```
UPDATE output_data 
SET expiration_date =
(select start_date 
 FROM input_data 
 where TN = output_data.source_id);

 INSERT INTO output_data(source_id, effective_date,provider_id)
 SELECT TN,start_date,operator FROM input_data;
```

[SQLFIDDLE](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/b2e16/9)

Exact same code works for mysql:

[SQLFIDDLE](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/f8895/1)

Comment: currently working on mysql, will do oracle after that

Comment: My fiddles keep coming up with invalid SQL statement  even though documentation supports that what I am writing should work for Oracle, Oracle y u no behave like all the others

Comment: @ Jeremy -These two queries gives expected result on oracle. Thanks for that !!! Is there any way to combine these to queries. So that in one run i can get the final result. Now i have to do run Update first then Insert. I am going to use this query in some other application where i need to pass single query to complete job

Comment: I don't think that's possible, however you could put these queries into a procedure and call that procedure I guess, a query can do only one thing at a time, here you are doing 2 (both update and insert) so I don't think it's possible with a single query